cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError) : but its not "ffi_c"
I have seen all kind of fix on the internet and stackover flow, those are c executable one with file error for "ffi_c" I'm getting error for ffi only. I'm getting this error previously too, and after moving to WSL and moved from 3.3.0 -> 3.3.3 using ASDF multi version manager. i got this issue. I had this issue before too, but then thought might changing to uppper version and new rails might fix that. but doesn't
C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/ruby.exe -x C:\Ruby33-x64\bin\bundle exec C:\Ruby33-x64\bin\ruby.exe D:/Learning/Language_Tools_and_learning/RailsPractice/untitled/bin/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development
C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:27:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/native.rb:3:in `<main>'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `<main>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.13/lib/bundler.rb:212:in `require'
        from D:/Learning/Language_Tools_and_learning/RailsPractice/untitled/config/application.rb:19:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:139:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:136:in `perform'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:178:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:73:in `perform'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/command.rb:71:in `block in invoke'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/command.rb:149:in `with_argv'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/command.rb:69:in `invoke'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
        from C:/Users/XYZ/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from D:/Learning/Language_Tools_and_learning/RailsPractice/untitled/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1

get this error of ffi on runnning server, pre compiling, sometime installing some gem.
I tried:

Reinstalled ruby with dev kit
changes folder
installed "gem ffi" in gem file
gem install ffi


This question is not about C (the error is a ruby error) is not about coding, as no code is presented, and not about programming, The error directs you to C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb line 74.  Why haven't you shown at least the offending line?

@LuisColorado I was not able to find the solution. So, I simply re-created the whole thing from scratch which then worked fine. and I'm not talking about C. you took it all wrong. I'm just saying to clear to other user those who faced ffi_c issue, so this doesn't get misunderstood as similar question.

Then it is better not to tag it as c, right?  You don't make me attend your question and lose time searchinf for the c problem :)
